# How can I change multiple ranges of cells background color with a script?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

First I am fairly new to JS. I have learned a bunch of it back in college and now I am brushing the dust off to get back at it.

In a previous formula I was able to clear multiple ranges of cells back to nothing with the push of a button. I now want to take a derivative of that formula and change the cells that are within the aforementioned ranges to a different background color.

Here is the "clear" formula:

```html
function clear1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Main Board');
  var rangesToClear = ['D25:I58','D62:I114','D118:I123','D127:I142','D146:I157','D161:I173','D179:I237','D241:I253','D257:I272','D276:I289','D295:I302','D306:I328','D332:I345','D349:I356','D362:I371','D375:I397','D401:I402','D409:I424','D428:I428','D434:I448','D452:I471','D475:I514','D518:I536','D540:I582','D586:I593','D597:I605','D611:I628','D632:I641','D645:I653','D657:I666','D672:I681','D685:I707','D711:I721','D727:I752','D756:I762','D766:I772','D778:I793','D797:I805','D809:I817','D823:I840','D844:I851','D857:I908','D912:I912','D916:I944','D948:I956','D960:I981','D985:I1004','D1010:I1031','D1035:I1051','D1056:I1064','D1069:I1079','D1083:I1094','D1098:I1110'];
  for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) { 
    sheet.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();
  }
}
```

I do not completely understand this formula as I was helped to make it. Here is my newer rendition to change the background of the cells. What I did was pare back the ranges in which I want the variables to hit.

```html
function colorup() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Main Board');
  var rangesMon = ['D25:D58','D62:D114','D118:D123','D127:D142','D146:D157','D161:D173','D179:D237','D241:D253','D257:D272','D276:D289','D295:D302','D306:D328','D332:D345','D349:D356','D362:D371','D375:D397','D401:D402','D409:D424','D428:D428','D434:D448','D452:D471','D475:D514','D518:D536','D540:D582','D586:D593','D597:D605','D611:D628','D632:D641','D645:D653','D657:D666','D672:D681','D685:D707','D711:D721','D727:D752','D756:D762','D766:D772','D778:D793','D797:D805','D809:D817','D823:D840','D844:D851','D857:D908','D912:D912','D916:D944','D948:I956','D960:D981','D985:D1004','D1010:D1031','D1035:D1051','D1056:D1064','D1069:D1079','D1083:D1094','D1098:D1110'];
  var rangesTues = ['E25:E58','E62:E114','E118:E123','E127:E142','E146:E157','E161:E173','E179:E237','E241:E253','E257:E272','E276:E289','E295:E302','E306:E328','E332:E345','E349:E356','E362:E371','E375:E397','E401:E402','E409:E424','E428:E428','E434:E448','E452:E471','E475:E514','E518:E536','E540:E582','E586:E593','E597:E605','E611:E628','E632:E641','E645:E653','E657:E666','E672:E681','E685:E707','E711:E721','E727:E752','E756:E762','E766:E772','E778:E793','E797:E805','E809:E817','E823:E840','E844:E851','E857:E908','E912:E912','E916:E944','E948:E956','E960:E981','E985:E1004','E1010:E1031','E1035:E1051','E1056:E1064','E1069:E1079','E1083:E1094','E1098:E1110']
  var rangesWed =['F25:F58','F62:F114','F118:F123','F127:F142','F146:F157','F161:F173','F179:F237','F241:F253','F257:F272','F276:F289','F295:F302','F306:F328','F332:F345','F349:F356','F362:F371','F375:F397','F401:F402','F409:F424','F428:F428','F434:F448','F452:F471','F475:F514','F518:F536','F540:F582','F586:F593','F597:F605','F611:F628','F632:F641','F645:F653','F657:F666','F672:F681','F685:F707','F711:F721','F727:F752','F756:F762','F766:F772','F778:F793','F797:F805','F809:F817','F823:F840','F844:F851','F857:F908','F912:F912','F916:F944','F948:F956','F960:F981','F985:F1004','F1010:F1031','F1035:F1051','F1056:F1064','F1069:F1079','F1083:F1094','F1098:F1110']
  var rangesThurs =['G25:G58','G62:G114','G118:G123','G127:G142','G146:G157','G161:G173','G179:G237','G241:G253','G257:G272','G276:G289','G295:G302','G306:G328','G332:G345','G349:G356','G362:G371','G375:G397','G401:G402','G409:G424','G428:G428','G434:G448','G452:G471','G475:G514','G518:G536','G540:G582','G586:G593','G597:G605','G611:G628','G632:G641','G645:G653','G657:G666','G672:G681','G685:G707','G711:G721','G727:G752','G756:G762','G766:G772','G778:G793','G797:G805','G809:G817','G823:G840','G844:G851','G857:G908','G912:G912','G916:G944','G948:G956','G960:G981','G985:G1004','G1010:G1031','G1035:G1051','G1056:G1064','G1069:G1079','G1083:G1094','G1098:G1110'] 
  var rangesFri = ['H25:H58','H62:H114','H118:H123','H127:H142','H146:H157','H161:H173','H179:H237','H241:H253','H257:H272','H276:H289','H295:H302','H306:H328','H332:H345','H349:H356','H362:H371','H375:H397','H401:H402','H409:H424','H428:H428','H434:H448','H452:H471','H475:H514','H518:H536','H540:H582','H586:H593','H597:H605','H611:H628','H632:H641','H645:H653','H657:H666','H672:H681','H685:H707','H711:H721','H727:H752','H76:H762','H766:H772','H778:H793','H797:H805','H809:H817','H823:H840','H844:H851','H857:H908','H912:H912','H916:H944','H948:H956','H960:H981','H985:H1004','H1010:H1031','H1035:H1051','H1056:H1064','H1069:H1079','H1083:H1094','H1098:H1110']
  var rangesSat = ['I25:I58','I62:I114','I118:I123','I127:I142','I146:I157','I161:I173','I179:I237','I241:I253','I257:I272','I276:I289','I295:I302','I306:I328','I332:I345','I349:I356','I362:I371','I375:I397','I401:I402','I409:I424','I428:I428','I434:I448','I452:I471','I475:I514','I518:I536','I540:I582','I586:I593','I597:I605','I611:I628','I632:I641','I645:I653','I657:I666','I672:I681','I685:I707','I711:I721','I727:I752','I756:I762','I766:I772','I778:I793','I797:I805','I809:I817','I823:I840','I844:I851','I857:I908','I912:I912','I916:I944','I948:I956','I960:I981','I985:I1004','I1010:I1031','I1035:I1051','I1056:I1064','I1069:I1079','I1083:I1094','I1098:I1110']
  for (var i=0; i<rangesMon.length; i++){
    sheet.getRange(rangesMon[i]).setBackground(color)
  }
```

As you can see I added more vars, one for each day of the week since each day needs to be a different color. Towards the end I fall short as I am unsure of exactly what needs to be added to make the color change. One other thing that I am having trouble finding is the color value in Google Sheets. Can I just point it to another cell to find the value and insert it or do I actually need to find the value?

Thanks for the help and any sort of education would be amazing in this sort because I am trying to learn a little more to stop these questions before they start.

UPDATE:Here is where I have gotten to know and it says when running colorUp that it cannot find the range on line 20 which is 
sheet.getRange(rangesMon).setBackground("#f4cccc");

What I don't understand is why it's not finding the range, it's a variable at the global level.

Thanks again for the help.

```html
function colorUp() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Main Board');
  var rangesMon = ['D25:D58','D62:D114','D118:D123','D127:D142','D146:D157','D161:D173','D179:D237','D241:D253','D257:D272','D276:D289','D295:D302','D306:D328','D332:D345','D349:D356','D362:D371','D375:D397','D401:D402','D409:D424','D428:D428','D434:D448','D452:D471','D475:D514','D518:D536','D540:D582','D586:D593','D597:D605','D611:D628','D632:D641','D645:D653','D657:D666','D672:D681','D685:D707','D711:D721','D727:D752','D756:D762','D766:D772','D778:D793','D797:D805','D809:D817','D823:D840','D844:D851','D857:D908','D912:D912','D916:D944','D948:I956','D960:D981','D985:D1004','D1010:D1031','D1035:D1051','D1056:D1064','D1069:D1079','D1083:D1094','D1098:D1110'];
  var rangesTues = ['E25:E58','E62:E114','E118:E123','E127:E142','E146:E157','E161:E173','E179:E237','E241:E253','E257:E272','E276:E289','E295:E302','E306:E328','E332:E345','E349:E356','E362:E371','E375:E397','E401:E402','E409:E424','E428:E428','E434:E448','E452:E471','E475:E514','E518:E536','E540:E582','E586:E593','E597:E605','E611:E628','E632:E641','E645:E653','E657:E666','E672:E681','E685:E707','E711:E721','E727:E752','E756:E762','E766:E772','E778:E793','E797:E805','E809:E817','E823:E840','E844:E851','E857:E908','E912:E912','E916:E944','E948:E956','E960:E981','E985:E1004','E1010:E1031','E1035:E1051','E1056:E1064','E1069:E1079','E1083:E1094','E1098:E1110']
  var rangesWed =['F25:F58','F62:F114','F118:F123','F127:F142','F146:F157','F161:F173','F179:F237','F241:F253','F257:F272','F276:F289','F295:F302','F306:F328','F332:F345','F349:F356','F362:F371','F375:F397','F401:F402','F409:F424','F428:F428','F434:F448','F452:F471','F475:F514','F518:F536','F540:F582','F586:F593','F597:F605','F611:F628','F632:F641','F645:F653','F657:F666','F672:F681','F685:F707','F711:F721','F727:F752','F756:F762','F766:F772','F778:F793','F797:F805','F809:F817','F823:F840','F844:F851','F857:F908','F912:F912','F916:F944','F948:F956','F960:F981','F985:F1004','F1010:F1031','F1035:F1051','F1056:F1064','F1069:F1079','F1083:F1094','F1098:F1110']
  var rangesThurs =['G25:G58','G62:G114','G118:G123','G127:G142','G146:G157','G161:G173','G179:G237','G241:G253','G257:G272','G276:G289','G295:G302','G306:G328','G332:G345','G349:G356','G362:G371','G375:G397','G401:G402','G409:G424','G428:G428','G434:G448','G452:G471','G475:G514','G518:G536','G540:G582','G586:G593','G597:G605','G611:G628','G632:G641','G645:G653','G657:G666','G672:G681','G685:G707','G711:G721','G727:G752','G756:G762','G766:G772','G778:G793','G797:G805','G809:G817','G823:G840','G844:G851','G857:G908','G912:G912','G916:G944','G948:G956','G960:G981','G985:G1004','G1010:G1031','G1035:G1051','G1056:G1064','G1069:G1079','G1083:G1094','G1098:G1110'] 
  var rangesFri = ['H25:H58','H62:H114','H118:H123','H127:H142','H146:H157','H161:H173','H179:H237','H241:H253','H257:H272','H276:H289','H295:H302','H306:H328','H332:H345','H349:H356','H362:H371','H375:H397','H401:H402','H409:H424','H428:H428','H434:H448','H452:H471','H475:H514','H518:H536','H540:H582','H586:H593','H597:H605','H611:H628','H632:H641','H645:H653','H657:H666','H672:H681','H685:H707','H711:H721','H727:H752','H76:H762','H766:H772','H778:H793','H797:H805','H809:H817','H823:H840','H844:H851','H857:H908','H912:H912','H916:H944','H948:H956','H960:H981','H985:H1004','H1010:H1031','H1035:H1051','H1056:H1064','H1069:H1079','H1083:H1094','H1098:H1110']
  var rangesSat = ['I25:I58','I62:I114','I118:I123','I127:I142','I146:I157','I161:I173','I179:I237','I241:I253','I257:I272','I276:I289','I295:I302','I306:I328','I332:I345','I349:I356','I362:I371','I375:I397','I401:I402','I409:I424','I428:I428','I434:I448','I452:I471','I475:I514','I518:I536','I540:I582','I586:I593','I597:I605','I611:I628','I632:I641','I645:I653','I657:I666','I672:I681','I685:I707','I711:I721','I727:I752','I756:I762','I766:I772','I778:I793','I797:I805','I809:I817','I823:I840','I844:I851','I857:I908','I912:I912','I916:I944','I948:I956','I960:I981','I985:I1004','I1010:I1031','I1035:I1051','I1056:I1064','I1069:I1079','I1083:I1094','I1098:I1110']
  for (var i=0; i<rangesMon.length; i++){
    sheet.getRange(rangesMon[i]).setBackground("#f4cccc")
  for (var i=0; i<rangesTues.length; i++){
    sheet.getRange(rangesTues[i]).setBackground("#d9ead3")
   for (var i=0; i<rangesWed.length; i++){
    sheet.getRange(rangesWed[i]).setBackground("#cfe2f3")
    for (var i=0; i<rangesThurs.length; i++){
    sheet.getRange(rangesThurs[i]).setBackground("#d5a6bd")
    for (var i=0; i<rangesFri.length; i++){
    sheet.getRange(rangesFri[i]).setBackground("#fff2cc")
    for (var i=0; i<rangesSat.length; i++){
    sheet.getRange(rangesSat[i]).setBackground("#d9d2e9")
  }
    }}}}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone that never used JS functions in Drive before, I found very simple to understand how it works from this question, so thank you for that :D.

When writing any function, you can use `CTRL+space` keys to see what commands you have available.
`setBackground()` works with any written color like `"orange"`, `"red"`, `"white"` ...
Or a color code like `'#000000'` to `'#ffffff'`.

Here is a simple example to color cells A1 to A10.

```
function test(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getRange("A1:A10").setBackground('#ffff00');
}
```

Be sure to keep the same name in your Spreadsheet and in the Script when you call it.

#### Taking your example, here another way to do it:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Main Board');
var rangesMon = ['D25:D58','D62:D114','D118:D123','D127:D142','D146:D157','D161:D173','D179:D237','D241:D253','D257:D272','D276:D289','D295:D302','D306:D328','D332:D345','D349:D356','D362:D371','D375:D397','D401:D402','D409:D424','D428:D428','D434:D448','D452:D471','D475:D514','D518:D536','D540:D582','D586:D593','D597:D605','D611:D628','D632:D641','D645:D653','D657:D666','D672:D681','D685:D707','D711:D721','D727:D752','D756:D762','D766:D772','D778:D793','D797:D805','D809:D817','D823:D840','D844:D851','D857:D908','D912:D912','D916:D944','D948:I956','D960:D981','D985:D1004','D1010:D1031','D1035:D1051','D1056:D1064','D1069:D1079','D1083:D1094','D1098:D1110'];
var rangesTues = ['E25:E58','E62:E114','E118:E123','E127:E142','E146:E157','E161:E173','E179:E237','E241:E253','E257:E272','E276:E289','E295:E302','E306:E328','E332:E345','E349:E356','E362:E371','E375:E397','E401:E402','E409:E424','E428:E428','E434:E448','E452:E471','E475:E514','E518:E536','E540:E582','E586:E593','E597:E605','E611:E628','E632:E641','E645:E653','E657:E666','E672:E681','E685:E707','E711:E721','E727:E752','E756:E762','E766:E772','E778:E793','E797:E805','E809:E817','E823:E840','E844:E851','E857:E908','E912:E912','E916:E944','E948:E956','E960:E981','E985:E1004','E1010:E1031','E1035:E1051','E1056:E1064','E1069:E1079','E1083:E1094','E1098:E1110']
var rangesWed =['F25:F58','F62:F114','F118:F123','F127:F142','F146:F157','F161:F173','F179:F237','F241:F253','F257:F272','F276:F289','F295:F302','F306:F328','F332:F345','F349:F356','F362:F371','F375:F397','F401:F402','F409:F424','F428:F428','F434:F448','F452:F471','F475:F514','F518:F536','F540:F582','F586:F593','F597:F605','F611:F628','F632:F641','F645:F653','F657:F666','F672:F681','F685:F707','F711:F721','F727:F752','F756:F762','F766:F772','F778:F793','F797:F805','F809:F817','F823:F840','F844:F851','F857:F908','F912:F912','F916:F944','F948:F956','F960:F981','F985:F1004','F1010:F1031','F1035:F1051','F1056:F1064','F1069:F1079','F1083:F1094','F1098:F1110']
var rangesThurs =['G25:G58','G62:G114','G118:G123','G127:G142','G146:G157','G161:G173','G179:G237','G241:G253','G257:G272','G276:G289','G295:G302','G306:G328','G332:G345','G349:G356','G362:G371','G375:G397','G401:G402','G409:G424','G428:G428','G434:G448','G452:G471','G475:G514','G518:G536','G540:G582','G586:G593','G597:G605','G611:G628','G632:G641','G645:G653','G657:G666','G672:G681','G685:G707','G711:G721','G727:G752','G756:G762','G766:G772','G778:G793','G797:G805','G809:G817','G823:G840','G844:G851','G857:G908','G912:G912','G916:G944','G948:G956','G960:G981','G985:G1004','G1010:G1031','G1035:G1051','G1056:G1064','G1069:G1079','G1083:G1094','G1098:G1110'] 
var rangesFri = ['H25:H58','H62:H114','H118:H123','H127:H142','H146:H157','H161:H173','H179:H237','H241:H253','H257:H272','H276:H289','H295:H302','H306:H328','H332:H345','H349:H356','H362:H371','H375:H397','H401:H402','H409:H424','H428:H428','H434:H448','H452:H471','H475:H514','H518:H536','H540:H582','H586:H593','H597:H605','H611:H628','H632:H641','H645:H653','H657:H666','H672:H681','H685:H707','H711:H721','H727:H752','H76:H762','H766:H772','H778:H793','H797:H805','H809:H817','H823:H840','H844:H851','H857:H908','H912:H912','H916:H944','H948:H956','H960:H981','H985:H1004','H1010:H1031','H1035:H1051','H1056:H1064','H1069:H1079','H1083:H1094','H1098:H1110']
var rangesSat = ['I25:I58','I62:I114','I118:I123','I127:I142','I146:I157','I161:I173','I179:I237','I241:I253','I257:I272','I276:I289','I295:I302','I306:I328','I332:I345','I349:I356','I362:I371','I375:I397','I401:I402','I409:I424','I428:I428','I434:I448','I452:I471','I475:I514','I518:I536','I540:I582','I586:I593','I597:I605','I611:I628','I632:I641','I645:I653','I657:I666','I672:I681','I685:I707','I711:I721','I727:I752','I756:I762','I766:I772','I778:I793','I797:I805','I809:I817','I823:I840','I844:I851','I857:I908','I912:I912','I916:I944','I948:I956','I960:I981','I985:I1004','I1010:I1031','I1035:I1051','I1056:I1064','I1069:I1079','I1083:I1094','I1098:I1110']
var ranges= [rangesMon,rangesTues,rangesWed,rangesThurs,rangesFri,rangesSat];
  
function clear1() {
  sheet.clearFormats();
}

function colorup() {
  for(var j =0; j<ranges.length; j++){
      for (var i=0; i<ranges[j].length; i++){
        sheet.getRange(ranges[j][i]).setBackground('#ffff00');
        //if empty, print "1";
        if(sheet.getRange(ranges[j][i]).getValue() === "" ){
          sheet.getRange(ranges[j][i]).setValue(1);
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Added a new array called range to explain one possible way to use all ranges with the help of arrays.
For every value inside the array, I check if the cell in that range is "empty", if so, the function prints a "1".
I hope this helps you.

Comment: Yep that works for changing the color but in order to take this one step further so that it will execute doing multiple cell ranges would I create a variable containing my ranges in a set as denoted above? Like rangesMon? 

or would it be that I just create a tone of lines like line 3 to make it work?

Comment: You don't need one line for each range, your way works perfectly, take a look at the code I've added.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I don't understand what you're doing with the first function that I already have working correctly, that one just needs to be left alone. My real concern is the colorUp function. 

I amended my post with the current function that I have put in there, can you take a look at that and tell me why it's not finding the range?

Comment: Thanks. My function `clear1` just removes all the styles in a sheet, like backgrounds or text colors. It doesn't remove text.

Now to your function.
First point. You are opening too many "for cycles" and not closing them when you should.
you need to remove all the `}}}}}}}}}}}}` you have in the end, and put them after each cycle like so `for (var i=0; i<rangesMon.length; i++){
    sheet.getRange(rangesMon[i]).setBackground("#f4cccc")
} /*close and call next*/
for (var i=0; i<rangesTues.length; i++){ ... } /*close */`

Also, instead of `"#ffff00"` you need to use `'#ffff00'`.